# how do I intercept api calls in javascript without knowing the caller function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, intercept

I'm new to the space and I don't know much about API calls.
so, I am developing this script to intercept API calls responses made by geoguesser, as you can see in one of the screenshots , the response has more than enough information to win the games.
so, can anybody point me in the right direction? tx :)
[image]

[image]

Comment: GET request URL's(in your example as well) usually contain ID of the data/object  your browser would receive dynamically on the state of your game. Unless the IDs are static, I am not sure how could you possibly identify the specific api network call and retrieve the data. I am not a gamer or anything. Just sharing my understanding. Can you share your script or code you have developed until now?

Comment: @optimalLight the script that I have developed has nothing to do with api calls.
I just need to console.log the api response , so I just need to know how to intercept these responses without finding them manually

Comment: @optimalLight, the only api call that the website makes is to google maps, so I can intercept them all , that's not a problem